# How do the sisters manage to get food enough for all of them in "What happened to Monday"?

Tags: plot-explanation, what-happened-to-monday

It seems the amount of food that a person buys is also monitored by the Government, e.g. the scene where Sunday buys food and its shown on a digital register of kind.

If this is the case, how are they even able to buy food for all the sisters ? They don't seem to suffer from malnutrition and also Cayman says something like how they've been taking someone else's food for 30 years.

How did they manage to get so much food for 30 years without raising suspicions (since is 1 visible portion and 6 hidden portions)?

Comment: This was a question I had towards the end...  They have 7 people living on the salary of one person.  Food, clothes, shelter, etc all has to be paid for by one salary or it has to be stolen.  Even if all purchases are not monitored, they have to pay for it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem a logic plot hole in the movie even if we explore all the possibilities:

1. **They stocked up** - Even if we consider that they stocked up their food supplies by cutting intake and stretch their rations it's not possible to feed all 7 of them for the long time.
2. **They get food from the black market** - This can also be a logical possibly since food is so strictly monitored and valuable its quite possible that there are "other" ways to get your hands on food supplies. But that should cost them a good fortune and they are getting salary only for one employee.
3. **It's just a mistake writers made!** - Finally even we think of all the possibilities and rack our brains all night we end up on a solutions that it's not possible to feed 7 people on 1 man resources.

It is indeed a logic hole in the movie.

Comment: it's been a while that I watched this, but is it possible that they eat out? that would help stretching the rations at home.

Comment: @Luciano If the government is monitoring what people buy for consumption at home, they're probably monitoring restaurant purchases, too.